# Espresso UI + Spoon run tests in series

Tags: android, android-espresso, spoon

I have a complete test suite for my app, and I've set up a build & test server which I'd like to hook up to my CI infrastructure, so that every night UI tests are run on a number of emulators.

Using spoon makes testing on multiple devices easy and nice due to included reporting, but it has a problem: it runs the tests on all currently running devices.

Now my build server is a humble machine and running 5+ emulators at the same time is impossible due to RAM requirements.

Is there a way to run the test in series, and possibly keep the same reporting for all of them with Spoon?

Comment: check `maxParallelForks` in `test{}` gradle config: https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html